# javascript included as php not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i am tryng to include a tag function much like we have here in stackoverflow. when i type tags and press enter a nice tag is formed  inside the text input. my problem is when the javascript/html php page is loaded alone it works.  but when i include this php in my main page it doesnt  work. 
here is my tag.php page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./src/jquery.tagsinput.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./src/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    function onAddTag(tag) {
        alert("Added a tag: " + tag);
    }
    function onRemoveTag(tag) {
        alert("Removed a tag: " + tag);
    }
    function onChangeTag(input,tag) {
        alert("Changed a tag: " + tag);
    }
    $(function() {
        $('#tags_2').tagsInput({
            width: 'auto',
            onChange: function(elem, elem_tags)
            {
                var languages = ['php','ruby','javascript'];
                $('.tag', elem_tags).each(function()
                {
                    if($(this).text().search(new RegExp('\\b(' + languages.join('|') + ')\\b')) >= 0)
                        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- body   -->
        <p><label>Tags</label>
        <input id="tags_2" type="text" class="tags" value="php,ios,javascript,ruby,android,kindle" /></p>
```

and here is my main page

```
<div id="insert" class="form-action show">
  <h1>Insert</h1>
  <p>

  </p>
  <form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <ul>

      <li>
        <?php include 'tag.php';?>
      </li>

      <li>
        <input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit" class="button" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

and if it helps, jquery.tagsinput.css

```
div.tagsinput {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto
}

div.tagsinput span.tag {
  border: 1px solid #a5d24a;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #cde69c;
  color: #638421;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 13px
}

div.tagsinput span.tag a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #82ad2b;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 11px
}

div.tagsinput input {
  width: 80px;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 5px;
  background: 0 0;
  color: #000;
  outline: 0
}

div.tagsinput div {
  display: block;
  float: left
}

.tags_clear {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0
}

.not_valid {
  background: #FBD8DB!important;
  color: #90111A!important
}
```

and main page css

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100);
@import url(http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css);
body {
  background: #1a1a1a;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.flat-form {
  background: #e74c3c;
  margin: 25px auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 450px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.red-form {
  background: #e74c3c;
  margin: 25px auto;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  padding: 15px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tabs {
  background: #c0392b;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tabs li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs a {
  background: #c0392b;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 22px 12px 22px;
  /*border-right: 1px solid @tab-border;*/
}

.tabs li:last-child a {
  border-right: none;
  width: 174px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.tabs a.active {
  background: #e74c3c;
  border-right: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.form-action {
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.form-action h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-action p {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

form {
  padding-right: 20px !important;
}

form input[type=text],
form input[type=password],
form input[type=submit] {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

form input[type=text],
form input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  color: #000000;
  outline: none;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.dark-box {
  background: #5e0400;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px #3d0100 inset;
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
}

.form-action .dark-box.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -24px;
}

.tabs + .dark-box.top {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  background: #136899;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px #2075aa;*/
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  transition: all 0.15s linear;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #1e75aa;
  /*box-shadow: 0 3px 1px #237bb2;*/
}

.button:active {
  background: #136899;
  /*box-shadow: 0 3px 1px #0f608c;*/
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-weight: bold;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-weight: bold;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-weight: bold;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-weight: bold;
}

select {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  background: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px 35px 5px 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #504848;
}

#black-text {
    color: rgb(242, 255, 63);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

#dbutton {
    border: none;
    display: block;
    background: #136899;
    height: 40px;
    width: 130px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px #2075aa;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
      -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
      transition: all 0.15s linear;
      font-weight: bold;

}

#dbutton:hover {
  background: #1e75aa;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px #237bb2;
}

#dbutton:active {
  background: #136899;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px #0f608c;
}

#mdbutton {
    border: none;
    display: block;
    background: #136899;
    height: 25px;
    width: 65px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px #2075aa;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
      -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
      transition: all 0.15s linear;
      font-weight: bold;

}

#mdbutton:hover {
  background: #1e75aa;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px #237bb2;
}

#mdbutton:active {
  background: #136899;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px #0f608c;
}

.datagrid table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.datagrid {
  font: normal 12px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #006699;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.datagrid table td,
.datagrid table th {
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.datagrid table thead th {
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #006699), color-stop(1, #00557F));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #006699 5%, #00557F 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#006699', endColorstr='#00557F');
  background-color: #006699;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-left: 1px solid #0070A8;
}

.datagrid table thead th:first-child {
  border: none;
}

.datagrid table tbody td {
  color: #00496B;
  border-left: 1px solid #E1EEF4;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.datagrid table tbody .alt td {
  background: #E1EEF4;
  color: #00496B;
}

.datagrid table tbody td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.datagrid table tbody tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.datagrid table tfoot td div {
  border-top: 1px solid #006699;
  background: #E1EEF4;
}

.datagrid table tfoot td {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px
}

.datagrid table tfoot td div {
  padding: 2px;
}

.datagrid table tfoot td ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.datagrid table tfoot li {
  display: inline;
}

.datagrid table tfoot li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #006699;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #006699), color-stop(1, #00557F));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #006699 5%, #00557F 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#006699', endColorstr='#00557F');
  background-color: #006699;
}

.datagrid table tfoot ul.active,
.datagrid table tfoot ul a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #006699;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: none;
  background-color: #00557F;
}

div.dhtmlx_window_active,
div.dhx_modal_cover_dv {
  position: fixed !important;
}


table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Is it giving any error in console? What is exactly not working?

Comment: @amol01 the tagging system is not working when i include. normally it is when i enter a tag and press enter a tag will appear inside the text input, and allows me to enter another tag. but when i include the php in the main page it doesnt work. console gives an error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tagsInput is not a function"

Comment: @amol01 but it works as a seperate tag.php page, when loaded seperately

Comment: @amol01 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByEVTVb-fnHQMDZraEM5RHRVOWc/view?usp=sharing   main.php doesn't work where as tag.php works perfect

Comment: Then the problem should be with php files. What are you doing there?

Comment: @amol01 there is no much php. im just using php so that i can include the    tag.php file. even if i copy the contents of the tag.php and include them manually it give same error. without any php

Comment: did you include your php file there like `include('your path to php file')`

Comment: @santosh yes <?php include 'tag.php';?>

Comment: '<?php include('tag.php'); ?>' is tag.php within the same directory ..

Comment: @santosh yes. tag.php loads. just not the way its supposed to. the way the tags are supposed to work is not working. santosh check my drive rar. the php alone loads nicely but it wont load the styles and all with include

Comment: could you please post your link

Comment: load your jquery in your main.php file .. :)

Comment: @santosh Thanks a LOT :D

Comment: you are welcome dude :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load you jquery in your **main.php head tag**

```
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>tag</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="enter.css">
            <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script> //changes here



</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="flat-form">
            <div id="insert" class="form-action show">
                <h1>Insert</h1>
                <p>

                </p>
                <form action="insert.php" method="post">
                    <ul>

        <li>
           <?php include ('tag.php');?>
        </li>

                        <li>
                            <input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit" class="button"/>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <script src="enter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```